# Jquery stop scroll when DIV hoover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, scrolltop

I really do not know where I have mistake

I need to stop scrolling in DIV when DIV ID="livelog"  is hover. Please help.

**HTML**

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
  <style type="text/css">
      #livelog {
    height:500px;
    max-width:1500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin:5px auto 15px;
    border:1px dotted #AAA;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
   color:#666;
   font-family: "Courier New",monospace
    }
    </style>
```

**Script**

```
// beginn parameters
var maxloglines = 200;
var pollintervall = 1000;
var aniduration = 10;
// end parameters - do not change things below

var parameters = "?lasttime=0";
var lastdebuglevel = 0;
var stoppoll = 0;
```

**Script - function for DIV:hover**

```
window.onload=function(){
$("#livelog").mouseover( function () {
    $('#livelog').stop(true);
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow')
});

$("#livelog").mouseout( function () {
    $("#livelog").animate({ scrollTop: $("#livelog").prop("scrollHeight") }, aniduration);
    $(this).css('background', '#FAFAFA')
});

}
```

**Script - continuation**

```
// manage the delivered data / loglines
function addLog(data) {
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(key, line) {
        var parts = line.split('|');
        if(parts[2]){ 
            if(parts[0] == 'debug') {
                setDebuglevel(parts);
            } else if (parts[0] == 'message') {
                if (parts[1] == 'nolog'){
                    stoppoll = 1;
                    $("#livelogdata").append('<li>' + parts[2] + '</li>\n');
                } else if (parts[1] == 'nodebug'){
                    $("debugmenu").remove()
                }
            } else {
                $("#livelogdata").append('<li class="' + parts[1] + '">' + parts[2] + '</li>\n');
                parameters = "?lasttime=" + parts[0];
                if ($("#livelogdata li").length >= maxloglines) { $("#livelogdata li").eq(0).remove(); }
                $("#livelog").animate({ scrollTop: $("#livelog").prop("scrollHeight") }, aniduration); // for scroll bottom
            }
        }
    });
}


// polling
function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "logpoll.html" + parameters,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            addLog(data);
            if(!stoppoll) {
                setTimeout("waitForMsg()", pollintervall);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            setTimeout("waitForMsg()", 15000);
        }
    });
}

// start polling
$(document).ready(function() { waitForMsg(); });
</script>
    </HEAD>
```

**HTML BODY**

```
    <BODY>
    <DIV ID="wrapper"> <!-- Start wrapper -->
<DIV ID="content"> <!-- Start content -->
<H3>Live Log</H3><br>
<DIV ID="livelog">
    <UL ID="livelogdata"></UL>
</DIV>
<DIV CLASS="debugmenu">
</DIV>
```

$('#livelog').stop(true); - not working

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don´t know how. Because the data in the UL are loaded via ajax every 1000ms. I tested with statis data in UL and all is OK. I tested too $("#livelog").hover(in,out) and it is too OK with statis data.

Comment: what version of jquery your using ?

Comment: jQuery v1.11.0. I tested 1.10 and nothing

Comment: Maybe use IF and remove $("#livelogdata").animate({ scrollTop: $("#livelogdata").prop("scrollHeight") }, aniduration); in function addLog(data). I solve it for three nights :-)

Comment: But for DIV:hover css style is working. Only I don´t know how to stop scrolling.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vemijeho/1/edit  Test with fixed data is OK

Comment: sorry buddy,i cant access jsbin, access violation. add the same to jsfiddle, i`ll check it

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. It is only for test with fixed data in UL.   http://jsfiddle.net/skyndas/Un7PG/